# Request permission to receive push on action

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I want ask user's permission only after user pushes button in ViewController. How can I do that?

In my code dialog popups after application launch. I can't execute *application.registerUserNotificationSettings* anywhere except AppDelegate class (i'm always getting errors).

*AppDelegate.swift:*

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Notifications
    let notificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings) // <-- that method popups dialog to allow/decline Push

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get when you execute `registerUserNotificationSettings` elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this where you want:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)`